# Convert Map into Json String to be persisted in db

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson, type-conversion

So far, I have these classes:

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private OrderContent content;

}
```

**OrderContent.java**

```
public class OrderContent {

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> content;

}
```

I am trying to persist `OrderContent` (which has only a map inside) as a Json String in db table (postgresql). I saw that I can create a custom converter that implements `AttributeConverter<K, V>` and define my own methods that will do the converting both ways.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this automatically, like an annotation or something so I don't have to define my own converter. I imagine this would be quite a common issue so there should be something.

Comment: Is it necessary that your Map is stored as a JSON string in the database? Otherwise [@ElementCollection](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/ElementCollections) could solve your problem

Comment: @Jakob I wouldn't really like to have 2 different tables, where one of them would have only 2 int fields, so I thought to persist everything in the same table and the json representation of map seems the most appropiate solution